# Reading Related Entites with EntityFramework Core (3.1.11) and SQLite

Tags: .net, sqlite, f#, entity-framework-core

I've found similar questions posted online, but none of them solved my problem, so I decided to describe it in details here.
Here's a simple One-To-Many relationship created with EF Core:

```ml
type Parent() =
    member val ParentId = Guid()                with get, set
    member val Name = ""                        with get, set
    member val Relatives = new List<Relative>() with get, set

and Relative() =
    member val RemoteKey = Guid() with get, set
    member val LocalField = ""    with get, set
    member val Parent = Parent()  with get, set

type TestContext(fileName: string) =
    inherit DbContext()

    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable parent : DbSet<Parent>
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable relative : DbSet<Relative>

    member this.Parent with get() = this.parent and set p = this.parent <- p
    member this.Relative with get() = this.relative and set r = this.relative <- r

    override this.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder: DbContextOptionsBuilder) =
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(dbConnection) |> ignore

    override this.OnModelCreating(builder: ModelBuilder) =
        builder.Entity<Parent>(fun entity -> 
            entity.HasKey(fun p -> p.ParentId :> obj) |> ignore
        ) |> ignore

        builder.Entity<Relative>(fun entity ->
            entity.HasKey(fun r -> (r.RemoteKey, r.LocalField) :> obj) |> ignore

            entity
                .HasOne(fun r -> r.Parent)
                .WithMany(fun p -> p.Relatives :> seq<_>)
                .HasPrincipalKey(fun p -> p.ParentId :> obj)
                .HasForeignKey(fun r -> r.RemoteKey :> obj)
            |> ignore
        ) |> ignore
```

The query below returns all the `Relative` records found in the db.

```ml
use db = new TestContext(fileName)
let relatives = 
    query {
            for r in db.Relative.Include(fun r -> r.Parent) do
                select r
          } |> Seq.toArray
// Assuming 'relatives' is not empty, this prints parent's name
printfn "ParentName: %s" (relatives.[0].Parent.Name)
```

The query explicitly requests to include the foreign record in the query by calling `.Include(fun r -> r.Parent)`.
However, this doesn't work in the other direction:

```ml
use db = new TestContext(fileName)
let parents = 
    query {
            for p in db.Parent.Include(fun p -> p.Relatives) do
                select p
          } |> Seq.toArray
// Even assuming that 'parents' is not empty and has related entries in the db, this prints an empty array
printfn "Relatives: %A" (parents.[0].Relatives)
```

The question is: how can I refer to the `Relative` records having a reference to `Parent`?

#### EDIT

I noticed that changing types definitions to F# Record syntax with `CLIMutable` Attribute fixes the problem. The question is: what's the difference between those two representations. I'm going to use ILSpy and will update shortly.

```ml
// This works with .Include(fun p -> p.Relatives)
[<CLIMutable>]
type Parent = 
    {
        ParentId : Guid
        Name : string
        Relatives : List<Relatives>
    }
and [<CLIMutable>] Relative =
    {
        RemoteKey : Guid
        LocalField : string
        Parent : Parent
    }
```

#### EDIT 2

I've worked out this is due to the fact the F# class does not allow `null` by default and my implementation is missing another constructor, that accepts all the parameters. So the complete definition that works with EF looks as follows:

```ml
    type [<AllowNullLiteral>] Parent(gid: Guid, field: string, relatives: ICollection<Related>) =
        member val Id = gid with get, set
        member val Field = field with get, set
        member val Relative = relatives with get, set

        new() = Parent(Guid.NewGuid(), null, null)

    and [<AllowNullLiteral>] Relative(pid: Guid, field: string, parent: Parent) =
        member val ParentId = pid with get, set
        member val LocalField = field with get, set
        member val Parent = parent with get, set

        new() = Related(Guid.NewGuid(), null, null)
```